# Database Relationship - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am having issues inserting data into my database tables. I have `users table` which is has a relation of one to many to `school table` and `region table`. That is, `users table` has `foreign keys` of `school and region tables`.

I have created the relations correctly but then when i try to insert values into the database, i get the error.

**PS**: I have one user(admins) in the user table (the school_id and region_id was inserted accurately) already which i saved through RegisterController. Now, when i sign in with the user(admin) already saved, i want to save other users through the UserController but then i get the error above.

What am i not doing right?. I am only a beginner with database relationship and laravel

```
General error: 1364 Field 'school_id' and `region_id`doesn't have a default value
```

meaning the field cannot be empty.

**UserController**

```
 public function store(UserFormRequest $request)
    {
        $user = new User(array(
             'name' => $request->get('name'),
             'email' => $request->get('email'),
             'password'=> $request->get('password'),
             'phone' => $request->get('phone')           

              ));
        $user->save();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are three solutions to your problem.

1

```
 public function store(UserFormRequest $request)
    {
        $user = new User(array(
             'name' => $request->get('name'),
             'email' => $request->get('email'),
             'password'=> $request->get('password'),
             'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
             'school_id'=>'you must pass value here',
             'region_id'=>'you must pass value here'        

              ));
        $user->save();

    }
```

2 Go to phpmyadmin make your school_id,region_id default value NULL. so you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is telling you that those fields can't be empty because they aren't nullable.

To make those fields `nullable()` in your users migration:

```
// Your create users table migration
$table->integer('school_id')->nullable();
$table->integer('region_id')->nullable();
```

(You can add any other properties to these - like `index()`, `unsigned()`, or foreign keys, etc.)